# Headphone media buttons as HID input

Tags: linux, wayland

How can I register `keyboard` (generally HID) events from a foot pedal?

I have a foot pedal that connects as a "microphone" to a 4 pin jack on my laptop and I want to use it with normal programs (my IDE, browser, etc.) as an HID.

I also want to be able to switch between normal headset and pedal HID on the fly if possible.

Possible solutions:

- Use `xev` to register media button presses as regular keyboard presses (not pretty)
- Use a script/daemon to monitor and translate them to the keyboard input I want (not pretty, the media shortcuts will register)
- Use a wayland "module" (I'm coming from `X.org` so this might not be even possible
- Use a kernel module (full driver)

It would also be nice to handle more than one key-presses but that's not my main focus.

Comment: So does the foot pedal already produce events on an `/dev/input/eventX` from the soundcard drivers? (Check by running `evtest` as root). If yes, it's easy to write a userspace program to turn those into real HID events (I can write details in an answer). This would be the equivalent of a kernel module, and is X/Wayland independent.